# Where can I find grid file of the Netherlands for R

Tags: data-request, geospatial, programming

I'm looking for a grid file (ideally 5x5 km) of the Netherlands, because I want to do kriging interpolation in R. 
Where can I find that?

Comment: what kind of grid?

Comment: Do you have GIS software? It's quite easy to create a grid in, eg, QGIS or ArcMap. Have a look at gis.stackexchange.com and you'll find the method explained in every widely used GIS software.

Comment: I found it myself already: https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2. This is the kind of grid I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself already [here](http://eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2). This is the kind of grid I meant.